# Pressure and Buoyancy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, buoyancy, fluid-statics

It is well known that you can trap water in a drinking straw by placing the tip of your finger over the top while the straw is in the water, and then lifting it out. The inner diameter of the straw is 0.5 cm; the height of the trapped water column inside the straw is 5.0 cm. Find the pressure in the air pocket between your finger and the water.

Comment: This is a site that is *not* meant as a platform to get your work done for you. As it stands right now, your question seems to simply ask for a solution, rather than showing an interest in understanding the underlying physics. As such, it is a "homework"-type question which does not show sufficient effort, rendering it *off-topic* on this site.

Please review our [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) to see what kind of homework questions are allowed here.

Comment: At these dimensions, the surface tension of the liquid will affect the answer significantly - so you will have to make some assumptions about the shape of the meniscus at either end in order to get the answer that reflects reality (as opposed to the answer your teacher is expecting). This is the only reason why the inner dimension of the straw matters, by the way...

Answer (score 1):

Well at the bottom of the water column, the pressure needs to be the atmospheric pressure.
Then, the law of evolution of pressure in a steady fluid is $ -\vec{\nabla}p=\rho g$. So the pressure in the water is $P(z)=P_a - \rho g z $.

At the top of the water column, the pressure is also equal to the pressure in the air pocket with $h=5cm$ the height of the water column. So $P_{pocket} = P_a - \rho g h $.

Is it ok for you ?